# Access home network

Tags: router, vpn

I would need to access the home network from external location, in order to have a public internet ip same as the home one. I know about creating a vpn server like with raspberry but I was wondering if it is possible to establish an external connection to the router in order to achieve the same result

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Firstly your home router has a firewall which blocks all incoming new connections in the first place, so you need to create a port forwarding rule to even get through that. That rule has to point to a device inside your network, it's not possible to create one that would send the traffic directly back out.

What you can do is run a VNC server on a computer in your home, then use VNC client to access the desktop of the home computer. Then you can use your home computer through the VNC client just the same way as you would sitting at it. The performance will be somewhat laggy, tho - a remote access can never be equal to local use, already laws of physics get in the way.

Comment: Thanks. Than I think the best option is to set up a vpn server inside home network

Comment: That'd be my tool of choice as well, I think it's the most flexible solution.

Comment: That is not entirely correct. Many routers have the option to connect to the router via a VPN, and not to use another network device as the VPN server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not going to work. You need to have a VPN setup in the target network first in order to connect externally.

Comment: A reverse proxy would also work.

Comment: Port forwarding to proxy inside the network to get back out, you mean? Depending on what exactly is needed I'd imagine that might make port forwarding a bit of an operation.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Maybe, I think I misunderstood the question. Can you explain what you mean by this? We could start a chat if you have the time...

Comment: @mully I got time :-) Reverse proxying isn't something I'm familiar with, hence didn't bring it up.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, the external connection you're talking about is, in fact, called a VPN. The main purpose of a VPN is really to make a "virtual" connection to a distant network, like you were actually there. So a VPN is a perfectly valid method.

But there are other ways to send traffic through a remote system – proxies which work at higher layers than VPNs (which deal with IP). Two most common types are HTTP proxies and SOCKS proxies, and they can be used if your intended usage is outbound-only and strictly just TCP. Many browsers and other apps support one or both types.

(I am specifically referring to "normal" or "forward" proxies, not reverse proxies.)

HTTP proxies, despite the name, can be used for any TCP-based service (e.g. HTTPS) through the "CONNECT" protocol command. SOCKS proxies are slightly more generic but achieve the same thing. Unfortunately both lack data encryption, and not all proxy-using apps even support password authentication.

One common and *secure* way to use SOCKS is to actually use SSH instead. SSH supports proxying TCP connections as well, and many SSH clients have a feature called "dynamic tunnel" which emulates a SOCKS proxy. So you can connect to an SSH server (including even some, but not all, home routers) and use it as a relay for your web browsing and other things that don't involve UDP or inbound connections.